# using many differents theme in the same MVC3 Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, themes

MVC3 Razor support themes,

Can I use many differents theme to render comopnents in the same view ?

i.e if I have 2 links  , I woiuld like to set the theme for link A to blue and link B to brown in the same view.

is that possible ?

Thanks

Comment: That's called element styling and has nothing to do with asp.net mvc which doesn't support themes by default (you need a third party of full themming). What you need is simply to set the style or a class for the links

Comment: lurn css, and everything will be easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each view can request one or more stylesheets.  Just be wary of naming conflicts.